# Property [materiaprima] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo un problema con el envio de los datos a la vista y como llamarlos a continuacion les muestro el codigo, la idea es poder ver en la vista tanto la informacion del producto como de la materia prima asociada a esta, la relacion es muchos a muchos, y ya que un producto puede tener varias materias primas y la materia prima puede necesitarse para muchos productos

Con el `dd` me doy cuenta que si estoy recibiendo al informacion de la relacion y todo el cual es el siguiente:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#564 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => App\Models\Producto {#563 ▼
      #table: "Producto"
      #fillable: array:6 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:9 [▶]
      #original: array:9 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "materiaPrima" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#570 ▼
          #items: array:1 [▼
            0 => App\Models\MateriaPrima {#601 ▼
              #table: "MateriaPrima"
              #fillable: array:6 [▶]
              #connection: "mysql"
              #primaryKey: "id"
              #keyType: "int"
              +incrementing: true
              #with: []
              #withCount: []
              #perPage: 15
              +exists: true
              +wasRecentlyCreated: false
              #attributes: array:9 [▶]
              #original: array:12 [▶]
              #changes: []
              #casts: []
              #dates: []
              #dateFormat: null
              #appends: []
              #dispatchesEvents: []
              #observables: []
              #relations: array:1 [▼
                "pivot" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#600 ▼
                  +incrementing: false
                  #guarded: []
                  #connection: null
                  #table: "itemProducto"
                  #primaryKey: "id"
                  #keyType: "int"
                  #with: []
                  #withCount: []
                  #perPage: 15
                  +exists: true
                  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
                  #attributes: array:3 [▶]
                  #original: array:3 [▶]
                  #changes: []
                  #casts: []
                  #dates: []
                  #dateFormat: null
                  #appends: []
                  #dispatchesEvents: []
                  #observables: []
                  #relations: []
                  #touches: []
                  +timestamps: false
                  #hidden: []
                  #visible: []
                  #fillable: []
                  +pivotParent: App\Models\Producto {#527 ▶}
                  #foreignKey: "producto_id"
                  #relatedKey: "materiaPrima_id"
                }
              ]
              #touches: []
              +timestamps: true
              #hidden: []
              #visible: []
              #guarded: array:1 [▶]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
  ]
}
```

los modelos

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;

class Producto extends Model
{
    protected $table = "Producto";
    protected $fillable = ['codigo', 'nombre', 'presentacion','precio_out','cantidad', 'foto'];

    public function materiaPrima()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(MateriaPrima::class, 'itemProducto','producto_id','materiaPrima_id')->withPivot('min_produccion');
    }
```

materia prima

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;


class MateriaPrima extends Model
{
    protected $table = "MateriaPrima";
    protected $fillable = ['codigo', 'nombre', 'unit','precio_in','cantidad', 'foto'];

    public function productos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Producto::class);
    }
```

El controlador usa esta funcion.

```
public function show($id)
    {
        //
        $datas=Producto::where('id',"=",$id)->with('materiaPrima')->get();
        return view('producto.show', compact('datas'));
    }
```

En la vista accedo asi al producto

```
 <tbody>
                            <tr>
                            @foreach($datas as $data)
                            <td>{{$data->codigo}}</td>
                            <td>{{$data->nombre}}</td>
                            <td>{{$data->presentacion}}</td>
                            <td>{{$data->precio_out}}</td>
                            <td>{{$data->cantidad}}</td>
                            @endforeach
```

Pero a la relacion con materia prima no puedo mostrarla pensé en un doble foreach pero tampoco me lo permite el error aparece en esta linea donde materiaprima no pertenece a al coleccion, no se como entrar entonces a los datos de materiaprima dentro.

```
  @foreach($datas->materiaPrima as $materiaPrima)
                            <tr>
                            <td>{{$matpri->codigo}}</td>
                            <td>{{$matpri->nombre}}</td>
                            <td>{{$matpri->cantidad}}</td>
                            <td>{{$matpri->pivot->min_produccion}}</td>
                            <td>
                                 <form action="{{route('ProductoController@eliminarMateriaPrima')}}" class="d-inline form-eliminar" method="POST">
                                    @csrf @method("delete")
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn-accion-tabla eliminar tooltipsC" title="Eliminar este registro">
                                        <i class="fa fa-times-circle text-danger"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </form>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </tbody>
```

Intente con el doble foreach y tampoco tuve suerte, no se si el error esta en la relacion o donde.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si revisas lo que `$datas` te devuelve va en este orden:

- Primero están los datos de los modelos de Producto
- Después vienen los datos de las relaciones de `materia prima`

Bajo esa idea hacer esto no es correcto:

```
@foreach($datas->materiaPrima as $materiaPrima)
```

Pues en ese nivel no están las relaciones de las materias primas, entonces considero que tienes que hacer 2 ciclos `foreach` pero de esta forma:

```
@foreach($datas as $producto)
    {{ $producto->codigo }}
    /*
        Los demás datos de los modelos de Producto
    */
    @foreach($producto->materiaPrima as $materiaPrima)
        {{ $materiaPrima->algo1 }}
        /*
            Los demás datos de materia prima
        */
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono perfectamente.